# Can I use two Gherkin Annotations on a single step implementation?

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Is it possible to use two different Gherkin steps on a step implementation?

```
@Given('a user signs up for a new "{country}" account')
@Then('Select "{country}" on country selector')
def choose_country(context, country):
    match country:
        case "Country A":
            context.country_code = "A"
        case "Country B":
            context.country_code = "B"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. It should recognize one step as not being implemented. Perhaps some steps shouldn't exist ? Here's a [link](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/?lang=java) to more information about the subject.

Comment: Thank you. For the above example, the `@Then` statement was not recognized.